# Log4j property file is ingored

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

For some reason, my log4j configuration file is getting ignored.

The configuration is file found in

```
C:\dev\pa-backup-restore-utility\BackupRestore\log4j2.properties
```

Here are the contents of the file:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=logs/backupRestore.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file

logger.file.name=log4j2.properties
logger.file.level = error
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout,logfile
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.logfile.ref=LOGFILE
```

The batch file that runs the class is located in the same directory as the configuration file.

The command from the batch file is run as follows:

```
set javaPath="%appDir%\jre\bin\java.exe"

%javaPath% -Dapp.properties.path=windows.app.properties -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.properties -jar backupRestore-jar-with-dependencies.jar -b
```

The entry in pom.xml for this is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's how a logger.info is called:

```
static void printWarning(String message) {
    logger.info("============== warning ===============================");
    logger.info("== " + message);
    logger.info("============== warning ===============================");
}
```

However, when I run the batch job, an info message gets displayed in the console:

```
[main] INFO com.sick.backup.util.Utils - ============== warning ===============================
[main] INFO com.sick.backup.util.Utils - == here is an example message
[main] INFO com.sick.backup.util.Utils - ============== warning ===============================
```

Also, a log file is no longer getting generated.

This was all working at what point. I'm trying to track down the version to make sure it matches, but the only change I've made is to upgrade the version of log4j-to-slf4j due to prevent a vulnerability.

Comment: `file:log4j2.properties` is not a valid URI. Did you try with an absolute URI or the relative path to your configuration file?

Comment: I think somehow the log file properties it was using were maybe outdated, not sure. I just copied from an example on the net and now it's working.